# How I know when a class is a Helper or a Service?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

i'm using DDD architecture in my project and I need to create a class to generate a GUID to use in another class.

This class that generate my GUID is a Infrastructure Service or a Infrastructure Helper?

How I know when a class is a Helper or a Service?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Service able to serve some clients, and often this is a [SOA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-oriented_architecture) specific entity.
Helper provides a set of methods which commonly are [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

From my point of view if a class which provides the GUID generation functionality stores or uses this GUID for further needs - it is a Service class, otherwise I would say it is a `Helper` because simply work by principle *do and forget* / *generate and forget*.

Often if you can make method a [static method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29#Static_methods) - this is a helper method, it does not depends on any class state and does not affect it as well.

Comment: Is it okay to put Helper classes in a seperate Helper package (i'm talking about Java in this case)

Answer (score 2):

Glad you found an answer but you might want to rethink the question itself. What is 'Helper'? There is no such pattern or stereotype in DDD or anywhere else. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436366/in-ddd-architecture-where-i-keep-helpers-classs/7438606#7438606). [Something]Helper is usually a sign of [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) violation or just a bad naming. For example if your language/framework does not provide Guid generation (which is [highly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid.aspx) [unlikely](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID%28%29)) you can create your own `GuidGenerator` class. The name should reflect responsibility.