# DDD and helper classes

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, cqrs, hexagonal-architecture

I create an application based on DDD and hexagonal architecture in conjunction with CQRS (without ES).

I'm stuck.

In one of the bounded contexts I have layers:

- Domain,
- Application,
- Infrastructure,
- Ui.

I think this is a fairly common solution.

Currently, no element of the application goes beyond its layer. I believe that I distributed everything wisely, according to all recommendations.

Therefore, I am not going to describe here what is contained in a given layer.

However, I have a big problem to find the right place for certain elements.

And so what to do with the classes generating slugs and UUID?

Perhaps I know too little, but based on the knowledge gathered, I do not see any place for them in any of the above layers.
Also, I wouldn't like to create something like 'shared' or 'common' layer.
For the moment I stopped at the solution to create interfaces for them in the application, and leave the implementation to the infrastructure.

Another thing that bothers me:
I have Alert entity. It is responsible for displaying notifications in the system. Some of them are randomly generated based on categories. As I use CQRS, the notification generator gets alerts not from the domain but as query models.

So which layer is suitable for such a generator? Can such a generator be considered a service?

I am counting on help.

Comment: This is a [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23886514/231316) that includes a follow-up by the author 2 years later that discusses utility/helper classes

Answer (score 1):

yeah why not. your solution sounds solid. especially if the application does not need to know the nature of the ID generation.

eg `UUIDGenerator` implements `IdGenerator`. the contract in application only specifies that it has to have "identity" properties.

I felt that, while "infrastructure" is a collection of all low level implementations of the other layers, and your implementation may reside there - common code that does not communicate with external systems and rather is some "library-like" code is sometimes packaged in a "util" package/module and used directly from everywhere as if was in the standard lib.

question is - do you really need dynamic dispatch like the interface-implementation relationship above? or is it rather a static call to a function `generateId`?